# Is there a Poset which has one maximal element but no greatest element?

Tags: order-theory

If there is exactly one maximal element, then shouldn't that element also be the greatest element of that Poset?

Comment: Please clarify what "greatest element" means.

Answer (score 4):

Take $X=\mathbb N\cup \{a\}$ (where $0\in\mathbb N$) and the relation $\leq'$ defined as the standard relation $\leq$ on $\mathbb N$, and additionally, define $0\leq' a$. Then, $a$ is maximal, but not greatest.